# smart_text from django-jenkins(sites-packages of my project) doesn't match with django 5.0.1 after upgrade. How to solve this problem?

Tags: django, django-jenkins

`jenkins test`

/../python3.11/site-packages/django_jenkins/runner.py", line 9, in <module>     from django.utils.encoding import smart_text

ImportError: cannot import name 'smart_text' from 'django.utils.encoding' (/../python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py) Exit with return error: 1

Comment: smart_text is removed in django 4 and django-jenkins is no longer mantained, so either you find alternative package or fix django-jenkins